# What is the difference between these two types URLs?

Tags: php, asp.net, url

I was developing a web crawler when I noticed this.

URL 1: http://www.techwyse.com/services/

URL 2: http://www.techwyse.com/contact-us.php

URL 1 doesnt have any extension like HTML or aspx.But it displays a page . Is is possible to know the exact name of the page being displayed? (it is not displayed in Browser)

What do we call these kind of URLs like URL2 ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: HTTP doesn't know the concept of file extensions, so both these examples are fully valid URLs. There is no page "behind" the second URL. (I know it's not what you're asking about, just as a side note)

Comment: Whats with the flurry of downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.techwyse.com/services/ refers to a folder on the webserver whereas http://www.techwyse.com/contact-us.php refers to an actual file on the webserver.

When you request a folder 4 things can basically happen:

1. The webserver configured to have 'default files' like index.html, default.asp, index.php and one of these is shown.
2. The webserver found no 'default' files and folder browsing is enabled and you will actually get to see all the files and subfolders
3. There are no default files and folderbrowsing is disabled and you will see the error message 'folder browsing is disabled'
4. SEO is used and the webservers internally refers that URL to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by URL Rewritting 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: It *can* be. Given the context, that specific example is probably done by naming a file `index.php`.

Comment: Is that URL rewriting or the web server just serving up the default document for the folder?

Comment: @David, Had it been the latter, it would have displayed http://www.techwyse.com/services/index.php in the browser , right ?

Comment: @Anath — wrong (unless the user explicitly visited `http://www.techwyse.com/services/index.php` instead of `http://www.techwyse.com/services/`.) Most servers will serve up a file from a list of possible index files if the URL maps on to a directory on the file system.

Comment: @David - but If you visit http://www.techwyse.com , it automatically takes you to http://www.techwyse.com/index-v.php.  (index-v.php is specified in the browser) . Please enlighten me.

Comment: @Ananth: Take a look at my answer why it is using index-v.php

Comment: @Ananth — then they must do some sort of redirect on that URL.

Answer (score 0):

That's called [SEO friendly urls](http://www.seoconsultants.com/articles/1000/urls).

and with PHP that can be achieved with the apache module [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

EDIT: Did not gone through posted links.

Here services is the directory hence the file name set with `DirectoryIndex` in `httpd.conf` file (usually index.php but one can change) will be executed.

You can also change that file using `.htaccess`.

Let's do a quick test to understand this.

Create a file inside `services` directory and name it (for example `test.php`)

Create a `.htaccess` file and add below line

```
DirectoryIndex test.php
```

and then go to http://www.techwyse.com/services/

You will see now `test.php` file is getting exeucted instead of `index.php`

Comment: usually correct, in this case it's not though. Here it's a regular directory.

Answer (score 0):

URL 1: is just calling a directory on the server and the webserver serves a default document.

In this case it's `http://www.techwyse.com/services/index.php`(same page as URL 1). You can try that this is not a coincidence by opening `http://www.techwyse.com/services/index2.php` which returns a 404.

Comment: I wonder where those downvotes are coming from when what i said is easily observable.

Comment: agreed... there are 4 answers here all with 2 downvotes, 1 upvote. In fact, all answers have at least one downvote!

Answer (score 0):

> URL 1 doesnt have any extension like HTML or aspx. But it displays a page. Is is possible to know the exact name of the page being displayed? (it is not displayed in Browser)

The name of the page will be the text inside the `<title>` element (assuming an HTML document). There is no way to know the filename, or even if there is a file to begin with. URLs resolve to resources and how the HTTP server determines the resource is an implementation detail of the HTTP server and utterly irrelevant to the client.

(Anecdote time: A friend was unimpressed by his university spidering the contents of his HTTP server and ignoring the robots.txt directives, so he wrote a script to generate random HTML documents containing random links, and let it spend a couple of days indexing utter nonsense on random URLs where the resources were all generated by `random.py`. There was no way to know that `random.py` was called `random.py` from outside the server (or even that it existed, although it was relatively easy to infer)).

The exact URL **is** `http://www.techwyse.com/services/` (there might be other URLs that resolve to an identical resource, but that one is as written).

> What do we call these kind of URLs like URL2 ?

URLs. (If you really want to distinguish them you could say "URLs with something that appears to be a file name in them").

Answer (score 0):

The first URL is either handled by something like mod_rewrite or a Java servlet (which can be mapped to any path), or it is simply a directory index. Most any web server will allow you to place a page with a given (often configurable) name in a directory, such as index.html or index.php, and have that page load by default. So, for example, www.mysite.com/ actually loads www.mysite.com/index.html. This works on subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the first type of URL you mention was created by simply having a file named "index" inside the directory named "services". Most web servers will by default look for a file name "index" if the URL does not specify a file.

Considering the fact that the 2nd example is a file with a PHP extension, it's likely that the file referenced by the first URL is "index.php".